# Would there be any interest in creating an incentive to answer Unanswered Questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yesterday I scrolled through Unanswered Questions because I could not face doing the grubby task I had to do.  There are some fascinating questions there that I think actually have answers,  but not easy answers.  I resurrected one of mine, and added a 250 point bounty.  I might do the same with another question.  But, before committing much more rep to bounties, I ask:

Is there interest in creating some kind of Contest or Event focussing on answering Unanswered Questions for a finite period (say a month, maximum ?)  If there are rewards, it might be "financed" partly by users willing to contribute some of their rep and partly by SE. Maybe in conjunction with the Hat event at the end of the year?

Answer (score 3):

I have given up on trying to get answer by offering bounties. Yes you get the question to the top but we do not seem to have any bounty hunters under our current users.
Maybe your experience will be different.

Also, reputation should build by experience, if some new user gets a few big bounties they get edit and review privileges which they have not learned to handle. Which is a reason for me not to offer big bounties.

Editing your older questions to have them float to the top might work as well as a bounty.

Comment: I think if folks want to put a bounty on, it may have some effect, so I wouldn't dissuade them, but like you I don't see any active bounty hunters here. And until we have a bigger core set of privileged users, I think that risk of new folks suddenly getting privs could be an issue.

Comment: Willeke and @Rory: I have to agree with your logic.  Pity!